# React Input adds 22px to the set Width

Tags: css, reactjs

My React input is set to 'width: 300px' in CSS. But on the screen, the width is '322px'. Here is all of the input CSS:

```
input {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 1px #818181 solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #818181;
}
```

Here is what the input looks like on the screen:

[image]

The 'Submit' button is the right length '300px'. But the input is '322px'. I inspected the input in Chrome and it says the width is set to '300px', but if you hover over the input the actual width is '322px'.

How do I make the input 300px?

Answer (score 0):

padding was extending the width of the input. The solution was to add this to the input CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```